# Establish FtpWebRequest through a HTTP proxy using the CONNECT method

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I try to establish a FTP connection using the `FtpWebRequest`. I need to establish the connection through a squid proxy server, that requires me to send a `CONNECT` command first.

I have tried the code below, but this results in a `GET` request to the proxy server, which it refuses.

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" +server);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pwd);
var webproxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://" + proxy+ ":" + proxyPort));
webproxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.Proxy = webproxy;
request.UsePassive = true;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Is there any way that I can use the `FtpWebRequest` to establish my connection through the proxy?

If not, do you know a good and hopefully free .NET FTP client that I can use?
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FtpWebRequest is a "session-less" client, so it doesn't allow you to interact with the remote end while connected.  I examined the code of FtpWebRequest.cs and I don't see how you can get it to send a "CONNECT" command.

"CONNECT" command doesn't seem to be part of the standard FTP command set, so I can't wrap my brain how this fits into something that an FTP library should do.

A good free FTP client that is session-oriented that I use is "SSH.NET Library" at http://sshnet.codeplex.com/ but I believe it only supports sftp.  FtpWebRequest supports ftps and ftp.  Find out if your FTP server supports sftp and you might be able to use SSH.NET .  If your only option is ftps, I can report that I spent a long time looking for a free .net  ftps client and I came away using FtpWebRequest.

Comment: FileZilla supports sending a Connect statement first. It is one of the options that can be chosen when you setup a generic proxy server in the properties. This made me assume that using the CONNECT method was some standard way of connecting through a proxy server. However my problem has been solved by having a little chat with our infrastructure department. They allowed me an exemption to the proxy server, so that I can connect directly to the FTP server without going through the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

`FtpWebRequest` supports HTTP proxy (and `CONNECT` command is mandatory part of that support). Your code is correct.

Though the HTTP proxy is not supported uploads (it is for all other operations). So maybe your actual problem is the upload, while you do not mention it.

For FTP uploads through HTTP proxy you have to use a 3rd party FTP client.

---

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library), you can use:

```
// Setup session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "example.com",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "mypassword",
};

// Configure proxy
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyMethod", "3"); // HTTP proxy
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyHost", "proxy");

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Upload file
    string localFilePath = @"C:\path\file.txt";
    string pathUpload = "/file.txt";
    session.PutFiles(localFilePath, pathUpload).Check();
}
```

For the options for the [`SessionOptions.AddRawSettings`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions_addrawsettings), see [raw settings](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings).

Easier is to have WinSCP GUI [generate C# FTP code template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code) for you.

Note that WinSCP .NET assembly is not a native .NET library. It's rather a thin .NET wrapper over a console application.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: It was a few years ago that I wrote this question. We got it fixed in the mean time. If I remember correctly, we got an exeption in the firewall, so that we could connect directly to the client FTP server without the proxy.